# C Bindings for LLVM Analysis

Tags: c++, c, llvm

Are there C Bindings for the LLVM Analysis Pass loops and intervals, or are they only available in C++?  I have tried looking for this and cannot find anything on it.  I know all of the bindings are in C++ and only some are available in C, but I need the C bindings.  Any documents or links would be helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: All of the LLVM libraries are C++.  If you need access to them from C, can't you just write a wrapper library?

Comment: @CarlNorum [Actually, not all of them.](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/group__LLVMC.html)

Comment: Oh, cool - are those not just themselves wrappers around the C++ libraries?

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes, they are.